# Filter dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (excluding `value2`):

```
condition condition1 date1      date2      value1 value2
A         X          2016-01-01 2016-02-01 1      2
A         X          2016-02-01 2016-03-01 2      NA
A         Y          2016-03-01 2016-04-01 3      NA
B         Z          2016-01-01 2016-02-01 4      3
B         Y          2016-02-01 2016-03-01 3      NA
```

I want to get `value2` column, with this code:

```
for (i in length(df$condition)){
  df$value2[i] <- filter(df, condition == df$condition[i] & date1 == df$date2[i])$value1
}
```

However I can't pass the `NA` values when one of the `date2` argument doesn't match in the dataframe.

Comment: What's the meaning of the `value2` column? How does it depend on the other columns?

Comment: `value2` must be `value1` when `date1` is equal to `date2`. I'd like to get the next month `value1` of `condition` in the same row.

Comment: Ok, `value2` must be `value1` if the dates are equal. But what does `value2` have to be when the dates are not equal?

Comment: It can be zero or `NA`, I've tried with an If statement but get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use a for loop here as it will slow down your code. Additionally, it is much easier using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

df %>%
  group_by(condition) %>%
  arrange(date1) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(as.character(date2) == lead(as.character(date1)), 
  lead(value1), NA)) %>%
  arrange(condition)
```

This code will generate the output:

```
  condition      date1      date2 value1 value2
     <fctr>     <date>     <date>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1         A 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      1      2
2         A 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      2      3
3         A 2016-03-01 2016-04-01      3     NA
4         B 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      4      3
5         B 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      3     NA
```

Note that you can drop the ifelse part in the case of the data you provided:

```
df %>%
  group_by(condition) %>%
  arrange(date1) %>%
  mutate(value2 = lead(value1)) %>%
  arrange(condition)
```

We can incorporate the second condition via group_by:

```
df %>%
  group_by(condition, condition1) %>%
  arrange(date1) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(as.character(date2) == lead(as.character(date1)), 
  lead(value1), NA)) %>%
  arrange(condition)
```

This will output:

```
  condition condition1      date1      date2 value1 value2
     <fctr>     <fctr>     <date>     <date>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1         A          X 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      1      2
2         A          X 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      2     NA
3         A          Y 2016-03-01 2016-04-01      3     NA
4         B          Z 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      4     NA
5         B          Y 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      3     NA
```

Comment: Yes, the loop slowed down the code. What if I want to add more conditions?

Comment: more conditions in the column conditions or other ifelse conditions?

Comment: If you add conditions like C, D and E in the first column you won't have to change anything in the code.

Comment: No, I mean, add another column so it serves as a condition. I guess I'll have to modify the `group_by`?

Comment: If you have another group of data you would have to modify group_by. Could you pls provide an example in your data (the column)?

Comment: Is this the desired output? We only have the combination A,X that returns on the following date so all other values will be NA

Comment: @capm What is the purpose of the additional column?

Comment: For example, I have a data set with parents and their kids, another column with dates and the last column with a flag whether the kid attended to school that day. I add a column with the next day for school and another column with the flag whether the kid attended that date. I have to use the column with the parents name and the kids name as a condition, because, many parents will have more than one kid. Thats why I needed the additional column. You answer was really well detailed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question already has an excepted answer, I believe the solution can be achieved with less lines of code than posted so far.

The OP has [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734673/r-filter-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions#comment76451574_44734673)

> I'd like to get the next month `value1` of `condition` in the same row.

This simply requires to apply the `lead()` function group-wise on `value1`. The `lead()` function is available in the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages.

With `data.table`, this becomes a one-liner:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(DF)[, value2 := shift(value1, type = "lead"), by = condition][]
```

> ```
>    condition condition1      date1      date2 value1 value2
> 1:         A          X 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      1      2
> 2:         A          X 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      2      3
> 3:         A          Y 2016-03-01 2016-04-01      3     NA
> 4:         B          Z 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      4      3
> 5:         B          Y 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      3     NA
> ```

The `dplyr` variant is similar to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735793/3817004) but somewhat streamlined, e.g., it's not necessary to load `magrittr` separately when `dplyr` already has been loaded.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = lead(value1))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 6
> # Groups:   condition [2]
>   condition condition1      date1      date2 value1 value2
>       <chr>      <chr>     <date>     <date>  <int>  <int>
> 1         A          X 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      1      2
> 2         A          X 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      2      3
> 3         A          Y 2016-03-01 2016-04-01      3     NA
> 4         B          Z 2016-01-01 2016-02-01      4      3
> 5         B          Y 2016-02-01 2016-03-01      3     NA
> ```

Note that both variants of `lead()` do fill up missing values with `NA` by default. So, there is *no* additional code requires to treat the last line of each group specially.

---

**Addendum**: The sample data set supplied by the OP is already sorted by `condition` and `date1`. As `lead()` depends on the order of rows in the data.frame, it might be worthwhile to ensure a proper order to be on the safe side:

`data.table` solution with ordering:

```
data.table(DF)[order(date1), value2 := shift(value1, type = "lead"), keyby = condition][]
```

`dplyr` variant with ordering:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  arrange(condition, date1) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = lead(value1))
```

Note that here only one call to `arrange()` is made instead of two in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735793/3817004).

Comment: This is similar to the code i posted first. However, you will not achieve the correct result if month are skipped within a group. Thats why we need the ifelse statement here

Comment: @Niko  Yes, this is why I explicitely referenced your `dplyr` answer. Concerning the second point, this might be true but it is not clear from the question or the provided sample data set.

Comment: Thx for the upvote. Yes you are right, it is not clear from the provided date set. In fact, I did not have it in my first solution as well :)